# SL Studio Lights. How to custom make your own?

Tags: lighting

I have been searching, without any luck, how to make studio lights, sl files. Anyone knowing where to find tutorials.

Comment: There is [an editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/lights.html#prefs-lights-studio), Just click the "gear" icon in the studio lights viewport menu or open preferences > lights > studio lights. In the editor, you can edit a light setup and save it as a new version. Import options are also available there. The file is saved in the preferences directory ("%appdata%\Blender Foundation\Blender\<version>\datafiles\studiolights\studio" for Windows).

Answer (score 0):

If you open blender's .sl files in notepad you'll see things like `light[0].col.z 0.507074` so you can copy and edit them yourself.